# Method not called in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react and I want to call `handleOpen` method when user clicked on button. I wrote following code but not work. why?

```
class Modal extends Component {
  handleOpen() {
    alert('open modal');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Open</button>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem could be because of the fact that You may not have imported the functions correctly

Comment: its working as expected, are you sure your code is only this much ?

Comment: this is working fine, see your console if there is any error, see that if Fragment is supported in your react version and you have imported it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
class Modal extends Component {
  handleOpen = () => {
    alert('open modal');
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Open</button>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

You forgot to bind "this" to the handleOpen method.